# I want to call call the mifinity api using php

Tags: php, json, api

I am using the following api:http://apidocs.mifinity.com/#/doc/2 but its not working??

My API key

```
$data = array(
    'key' => "1234567777"
);
$url = 'https://demo.mifinitypay.com/';
$ch = curl_init($url);
$postString = http_build_query($data, '', '&');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postString);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
var_dump($response);
```

Comment: Not working in what way? Are you getting errors? Have you checked your error logs?

Comment: its returning nothing

Comment: Have you checked your error logs?

Comment: yes I did and won't get any error.

Comment: I am able to fox this just by using HttpRequest() class of PHP rather then CURl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$request = new HttpRequest();
$request->setUrl('https://demo.mifinitypay.com/api/oauth/token');
$request->setMethod(HTTP_METH_POST);

$request->setHeaders(array(
  'postman-token' => '6396dfb7-540b-0e7d-7333-5d0eeff4d606',
  'cache-control' => 'no-cache',
  'authorization' => 'Basic username:password encoded using Base64',
  'x-api-version' => '1',
  'accept' => 'application/json',
  'content-type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
));

$request->setContentType('application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
$request->setPostFields(array(
  'grant_type' => 'client_credentials'
));

try {
  $response = $request->send();

  echo $response->getBody();
} catch (HttpException $ex) {
  echo $ex;
}
```

Comment: Unless you're considering this the answer to your original question you should not post code as an answer. Edit your original post to add any new information.